# junitResult.xml from jenkins home directory to jenkins slave

Tags: jenkins, junit

I have some regression tests running on jenkins. Each testcase produces a nosetests.xml that is used to get the junitResult.xml (is found on the jenkins home directory).

I want to copy/save the junitResult.xml(on jenkins home directory) to the slave workspace using pipeline.

How can I do this?

**Edit**
My team has removed any access to the master. It seems however that the junitResult.xml file is found in the home directory. Is it possible to save this file elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [stash](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#stash-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build) and [unstash](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#unstash-restore-files-previously-stashed) pipeline keywords to achieve what you want.
The `stash` keyword saves a set of files for later use on any node/workspace in the same Pipeline run, and the `unstash` restores a set of files previously stashed into the current workspace.

In your case, on the master you can stash the `junitResult.xml` file and later on unstash it to the workspace of the agent you want.

Comment: Hi! Is it possible to save junitResult.xml to a slave instead of it saving to the default master (jenkins home directory)?

Comment: @IshiraLiyanage when you use the `unstash` method it will un stash it on the current running node (which can also be the master if you want)

Comment: @Noah Thanks but unfortunately, my team does not want to execute any jobs on master (I can't even stash folders). It seems however that the junitResult.xml file is found in the home directory. Is it possible to save this file elsewhere? For instance could we give the path for the junitResult file to be saved in a slave?

Comment: `stash` and `unstash` can be executed on any slave, and no need for running on the master node. the `junitResult.xml` will reside on the node in which you executed the tests. If you use a publisher step and will always publish it to the master so it will be available without and dependencies in the nodes - that cannot be changed.

Comment: Just to clarify this step will always publish it to master? There's noway to publish it elsewhere ?                                                                                                                       
 `junit testResults:'*/API-testcases/nosetests.xml', keepLongStdio: true`